# SQL on Oracle: Already joined two tables, now i want another column from another table(another join)

Tags: sql, oracle11g, inner-join

I have three tables;
1. Students - id, name
2. Subjects - sid,sname
3. Results - id,sid,marks (id and sid are foreign keys referenced by the two tables above)

Now, i perform

```
SELECT s.sname AS SubjectName, MAX(r.marks) AS MaxMarks
FROM subjects s, results r
WHERE s.sid=r.sid
GROUP BY r.sid, s.sname
ORDER BY r.sid
```

and i get The Subject Name with the maximum marks scored in them.
Now further, i also want the student name that has scored these max marks.

So i tried adding the column r.id, didn't work. I tried adding the table students in this query. I'm probably goofing up with the grouping after adding the table or something?

I did this

```
SELECT r.id AS StudentID, s.sname AS SubjectName, MAX(r.marks) AS MaxMarks
FROM subjects s, results r
WHERE s.sid=r.sid
GROUP BY r.sid, s.sname, r.id
ORDER BY r.sid
```

and i got each StudentID, with repeated subjects and the marks scored.
Whereas what i basically want is the student who has scored the highest in each subject.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Also show what you tried and what happened on that effort.

Comment: Similarly if i do this, i can get the student name and the max marks of his in each subject. But adding the column of subject name gets me repeated results as mentioned. 

`SELECT t.name, MAX(r.marks)
FROM students t, results r
WHERE t.id=r.id
GROUP BY t.id, t.name`

Comment: @GordonLinoff ddesired results are simply, getting the name of the topper in each subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use ROW_NUMBER() to tag the student who marked the highest on each subject

```
SELECT st.name,
       sj.sname,
       r.marks
  FROM (SELECT id,
               sid,
               marks,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sid 
                                      ORDER BY marks DESC) maxmarks
          FROM results) r
  JOIN students st
    ON r.id = st.id
  JOIN subjects sj
    ON r.sid = sj.sid
 WHERE r.maxmarks = 1
```

Comment: Does exactly what i need, brilliant!

Comment: you may close this question by checking on the right answer. thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can simple add  the new join, and i suggest you the use of explicit join sintax

```
SELECT t.name, s.sname AS SubjectName, MAX(r.marks) AS MaxMarks
FROM subjects s
INNER JOIN  results r ON  s.sid=r.sid
INNER JOIN  Students t ON t.id = r.id
GROUP BY r.sid, s.sname, t.name
ORDER BY r.sid
```

In the implicit join sintax should be

```
  SELECT s.sname AS SubjectName, MAX(r.marks) AS MaxMarks
  FROM subjects s, results r, stundet t
  WHERE s.sid=r.sid
  and t.id = r.id 
  GROUP BY r.sid, s.sname, t.name
  ORDER BY r.sid
```